# How can I efficiently recreate a similar triangle mosaic design in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, abstract

[image: Abstract Triangles]

I've considered doing it triangle by triangle but that seems a tad inefficient. Would there be another way I could make this more efficient?

Comment: would you accept Illustrator? It's easier for patterns that have systematic repeat and change at the same time.

Comment: Buy the photo? :-)

Comment: If you need to use Photoshop then [here is a tip, and possible duplicate](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41211/what-is-this-kind-of-pattern-called-and-how-is-it-created/41212#41212)

Answer (score 1):

The right tool to use is Illustrator, not Photoshop.

Making evenly spaced lines at four slants (horizontal, vertical, and both diagonal directions) and combining them in a "Live Paint Group" will get you about 90% of the way there; the rest is just choosing colors and clicking to fill.

---

If you don't have Illustrator available and this is just for curiosity/learning project, choose some project more suitable for Photoshop as this is really *not* where Photoshop's strength lies.  You *can* do it, but it will be hard and weird and you won't learn what the tool is really for.

---

If you don't have Illustrator and you actually need an image with this design for a real project, buy the image.  ;)

Comment: Or use Inkscape.